# Can we scale a curve relative to the distance between two objects? I tried doing it in geometry nodes, but curves aren't supported there

Tags: bezier-curves, transforms, geometry-nodes, geometry

[image]

[image]

This is what I made. It works well in scaling meshes, but I can't seem to do anything about curves.

Comment: Try the node `Transform`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the simple transform node for that. Just calculate the scale you need from your two objects and use e.g. this node setup:

[image]